# datepicker taking 01-01-1970 date

Tags: mysql

Here, I am using datepicker for inserting date.
I have defined datatype for date is like,

```
field name : date
datatype : datetime
default : As defined 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

When I am going to insert the values, but I am not inserting this `date` field.
So, it gives me like `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.
I want to add as `0000-00-00 00:00:00` if I not insert the date.

What should I have to do?

Comment: why cant you set default value for the field/

Comment: Are you using jquery.?

Comment: @anto.nishanth : I have setted already as I have defined in my question.

Comment: @DilipKumarYadav : No I am not using jquery.

Comment: @ViralBhoot in database for the said field edit and update default as `0000-00-00 00:00:00` I checked on my dummy db it is working fine

Comment: which server side language you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like Change your column `datatype` to `TIMESTAMP`

```
DROP TABLE mytablexxx;
CREATE TABLE mytablexxx (
  mydate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00')

INSERT INTO mytablexxx
VALUES();

SELECT * FROM mytablexxx;
// O/p - 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

And I think Yours is also working with `DATETIME`.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytablexxx;
CREATE TABLE mytablexxx (
  mydate DATETIME DEFAULT 0,
  mycolumn VARCHAR(36)
);

INSERT INTO mytablexxx(mycolumn) VALUES(UUID());
INSERT INTO mytablexxx(mycolumn) VALUES(UUID());
INSERT INTO mytablexxx(mycolumn) VALUES(UUID());


SELECT * FROM mytablexxx;

// O/p - 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

To select Date only

```
SELECT DATE(mydate) from tableName
```

You can check functions like `DATE()`, `DAY()`, `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`

Comment: Its working good...!!
Can I use timestamp only for date?
I mean I want to display date by default as 0000-00-00.

Comment: If you'll `SELECT DATE(mydate) FROM mytablexxx;` then it will select what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datet` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dob` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `name` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then run like `INSERT INTO datet (name) values ('King')`

Then check your table